# Spring boot reading parameters from AWS parameter store

Tags: java, spring, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, aws-parameter-store

I created spring boot(gradle) application, and included dependency: 
`org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-aws-parameter-store-config`.

I want to use `AWSSimpleSystemsManagement` to read configuration from AWS parameter store, but I am forced to write it like this (in aws):

```
 config/application_dev/server.port: 8080
```

Is there any way to read something like this from spring boot: `dev.application.server.port:8080`

currently all of this is managed from autoconfiguration I think, is there a way to override it

Comment: https://medium.com/@ashoksl/spring-boot-with-aws-parameter-store-d94368fef55c, one of the links I followed

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In **application.properties** you can define property `server.port=8081`.

The [parameter formats](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-aws/2.2.0.RELEASE/reference/html/#integrating-your-spring-cloud-application-with-the-aws-parameter-store) supported by **spring-cloud-starter-aws-parameter-store-config** are:

- `/config/application/server.port`
- `/config/application_dev/server.port`
- `/config/my-service/server.port`
- `/config/my-service_dev/server.port`

By defining the following properties in the **bootstrap.properties** you can change the format in some way:

```
spring.application.name=my-service
aws.paramstore.prefix=/config
aws.paramstore.defaultContext=application
aws.paramstore.profileSeparator=_
```

But only a simple customisations are supported because the main parameter naming logic is hardcode in the [`AwsParamStorePropertySourceLocator`](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-aws/blob/master/spring-cloud-aws-parameter-store-config/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/aws/paramstore/AwsParamStorePropertySourceLocator.java).

To dramatically change the parameter format you have to define a custom `PropertySourceLocator` and register it as bootstrap configuration.

The problem is that `dev.application.server.port` is invalid parameter name.

AWS Systems Manager Parameter Store uses `/` as a path separator and Spring uses the operation [get-parameters-by-path](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ssm/get-parameters-by-path.html). 
A workaround is to use name `dev.application/server.port`.

But this name is invalid also.
Parameter name must be a fully qualified name, so the valid name is **`/dev.application/server.port`**.

To support such parameter format define a custom `PropertySourceLocator`

```
@Configuration
public class CustomAwsParamStorePropertySourceLocator implements PropertySourceLocator {

  private static final Logger LOGGER =
      LoggerFactory.getLogger(CustomAwsParamStorePropertySourceLocator.class);

  private AWSSimpleSystemsManagement ssmClient;

  private List<String> contexts = new ArrayList<>();

  public CustomAwsParamStorePropertySourceLocator(AWSSimpleSystemsManagement ssmClient) {
    this.ssmClient = ssmClient;
  }

  public List<String> getContexts() {
    return contexts;
  }

  @Override
  public PropertySource<?> locate(Environment environment) {
    if (!(environment instanceof ConfigurableEnvironment)) {
      return null;
    }

    ConfigurableEnvironment env = (ConfigurableEnvironment) environment;

    List<String> profiles = Arrays.asList(env.getActiveProfiles());

    String defaultAppName = "application";
    this.contexts.add("/" + defaultAppName + "/");
    addProfiles(this.contexts, defaultAppName, profiles);

    String appName = env.getProperty("spring.application.name");
    this.contexts.add("/" + appName + "/");
    addProfiles(this.contexts, appName, profiles);

    Collections.reverse(this.contexts);

    CompositePropertySource composite = new CompositePropertySource("custom-aws-param-store");

    for (String propertySourceContext : this.contexts) {
      try {
        composite.addPropertySource(create(propertySourceContext));
      } catch (Exception e) {
        LOGGER.warn("Unable to load AWS config from " + propertySourceContext, e);
      }
    }

    return composite;
  }

  private void addProfiles(List<String> contexts, String appName, List<String> profiles) {
    for (String profile : profiles) {
      contexts.add("/" + profile + "." + appName + "/");
    }
  }

  private AwsParamStorePropertySource create(String context) {
    AwsParamStorePropertySource propertySource =
        new AwsParamStorePropertySource(context, this.ssmClient);
    propertySource.init();
    return propertySource;
  }
}
```

and register it in the bootstrap context by adding a file `META-INF/spring.factories`

```
org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapConfiguration=\
com.example.CustomAwsParamStorePropertySourceLocator
```

Comment: is it possible to do this without spring.factories file? some annotation maybe

Comment: A `spring.factories` is the only way Spring Cloud provides to register a new `PropertySouceLocator` - https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-commons/multi/multi__spring_cloud_context_application_context_services.html#customizing-bootstrap-property-sources

Comment: How can we disable existing AwsParamStorePropertySourceLocator?

Comment: Even though this new PropertySourceLocator is being injected, the default one from SpringBoot is still kicking in. How can we disable it?

Answer (score 1):

Try this [spring-boot-and-aws-parameter-store](https://source.coveo.com/2018/08/03/spring-boot-and-aws-parameter-store/)

https://github.com/coveooss/spring-boot-parameter-store-integration

Answer (score 0):

You need yo create a bootstrap.propeties file in order to configure the root path 
add "aws.paramstore.prefix = dev" to the file to replace "config"

please refer to:
https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-aws/2.0.0.RELEASE/multi/multi__cloud_environment.html
section 3.2